# Source env variables from bitbake-made sdk using Fish

Tags: sdk, yocto, bitbake, fish

When you compile a SDK using bitbake and have to `source` like :

```
source /opt/poky/.../environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

It can't be accomplished through fish, which is expected as the `export` sintaxe is different (i.e. `set -x ...`). I tried even to add `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, which also doesn't work. Does anyone knows a good way for it?

***Workaround***: Nowadays I run a bash inside the fish prompt to be able to compile binaries, which is not the best way but works. Don't let those small things push oyu away from fish :)

Comment: Have you tried using any fish plugins for that? E.g. [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass), [bax](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fish-bax), [fenv](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-foreign-env)

Comment: Bass did not worked, but [bax](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fish-bax) did! Thank you
Gonna quote you on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@charego mentioned some good ideas, thanks! :)

### [Fish-bax](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fish-bax)

So you can run it as:

`bax 'source /opt/poky/.../environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi'`

The only down side is that the auto completion does not work inside quotes, so one will need to write the whole path to the file. Although it's still better to have a fish running on top of a bash.

### [Bass](https://github.com/edc/bass)

Bass did *not* worked, as it crashs with: `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

### [Foreign-env](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-foreign-env)

Foreign-env also didn't work. It's possible to to set the variable, although it threw warning:
`warning: include location "/usr/local/include" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]`
and it does not compiles, probably it misses a few variables to `export`.

**TL;DR** Go with Fish-bax, at least it works :)

---

**Edit after 3 years.**

### [Replay.fish](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/replay.fish)

Currently, this is my choice.